# How do you pause/resume MyCounter from the same button?

Tags: java, android, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm rather new to Android (I've been programming nigh on a month and it feels as though I've been battling with this question for the majority of that time!)

I'm trying to create a timer app. At the moment there are two buttons one that starts the timer (if pressed again it resets the time back to 0) and a stop button which pauses the timer (and if pressed again does nothing).

I'm trying to make these buttons do the following:

- button 1 =  if pressed once start timer. if pressed when timer is running it pauses and if it pressed when the timer is paused it resumes
- button 2 = if pressed it restarts the timer

My java code is as follows:

```
    //within on create
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);

    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("30"); // starting from 30.

    final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(30000,1000);
    start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });
}

public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer{

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        System.out.println("Timer Completed.");
        tv.setText("Timer Completed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished  ) {
        tv.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000 + ":" +  millisUntilFinished/100));
        System.out.println("Timer  : " + (millisUntilFinished/1000));
    }
}
```

I think I'm going to have to save and restore instance states to pause and resume the timer and i will have to use boolean to change the onclicklistner of button1 ('start') ie. if timer is running and button1 clicked do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the onTick method record the remaining milliSeconds to a variable. Then, when you press the button on the 2nd time create a new CountDownTimer with the remaining time you recorded in the onTick() method.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, I do however have a few more questions... How do I record the remaing time to an int? and when I create the second CountDown do I use Boolean/ how do i destiguish between what countdown timer should be running? I am rather new to all of this so still getting used to it.